# Fixing a Git SVN Repository with submodules

Tags: git, svn, git-submodules

I have a Git repo cloned with Git-SVN and am now trying to push it back into SVN. The standard

```
git svn rebase
git svn dcommit
```

works fine until the point where a submodule was added.

After reading the docs (*after* of course wasn't ideal) it turns out that using submodules in a git<->svn repo is a bad, unsupported, idea. With all the power of Git though I figured there would be a way to fix this.

I've tried using **filter-branch** to completely eliminate any reference to the .gitmodules file and removed all relevant config entries

I've tried rebasing out of existense the commit where the submodule was added.

I've tried creating a new branch with just the commits I want to add to SVN (i.e. the ones made after the submodule was created) and dcommitting that.

I've tried giving **dcommit** specific revisions but it seems to ignore me.

Basically any SO answer related to removing a submodule, rebasing and/or dcommitting I've read and tried.

I keep thinking there must be a way to isolate the commits that are missing from SVN (from the commit that added the submodule -> HEAD) and just dcommit those but I can't for the life of me find it.

Comment: Why just not to clone SVN repository from scratch? If you want to use Git access to the SVN repository you may install SubGit into it. It will create a linked Git repository, so you can add submodules to it. And you'll still be able to use SVN interface.

Comment: Cloning the SVN repo wasn't the problem though; That was easy :) The scenario here was a trial of whether Git worked in a teams workflow. I needed to get the commits done during the trial back into SVN.